# When dealing with an issue of Maarit Ayin, can someone just make a sign with a piece of paper to let people know what things are?

Tags: marit-ayin

If someone is cooking or eating meat with almond milk, would a sign that says almond milk, work just as well (if not better) than actual almonds? Are there any sources that say a written sign works or doesnt work?

Answer (score 1):

With regards to basar bchalav,and pareve items which look like dairy ,or items that look like meat and are pareve the concern of maryis ayin come into play.

The Badei Hashulchan 87:47 notes that leaving the container or wrapper and writing on that what it is,is sufficient . However, in his Biurim he notes that writing on a separate paper "almond milk" without using the container or wrapper is not a sufficient siman.

Text :

[image]